# How to delay TradingView Alerts after sometime when the alert has been generated

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to delay the alert after sometime (say 15 seconds) the alert was generated in TradingView. But the alerts is not storing in the variable. They trigger simultaneously. Is there some other way to do this?.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Delayed Alert Example", overlay=true)

delay = input(15, 'Time Delay')*1000 // convert seconds to milliseconds

// Define a variable to store the time of the last alert
var lastBuySignalTime = 0
var lastSellSignalTime = 0


// Condition for the signals
BUY = open < close 
SELL = open > close 

plotshape(BUY , title='Long', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(SELL , title='Short', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar)

// Delay the alert by given time
if BUY 
    alert("Buy Signal", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    lastBuySignalTime := timenow

if BUY and (lastBuySignalTime >= delay)
    alert("Delayed Buy Signal", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    
if SELL 
    alert("SELL Signal", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    lastSellSignalTime := timenow

if SELL and (lastSellSignalTime >= delay)
    alert("Delayed SELL Signal", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue in the declaration of the time delay. Try the following:

```
if BUY and (timenow - lastBuySignalTime >= delay)
    alert("Delayed Buy Signal", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    
if SELL and (timenow - lastSellSignalTime >= delay)
    alert("Delayed SELL Signal", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't solve the issue in fact the alert is not triggering at all. It is not delaying the alert. Do you have any other solution.

Comment: What is the timeframe you're using?

Comment: 5 minutes timeframe

Comment: And I want to delay 1 minute after the signal was provided. For testing i used 15 seconds delay

Comment: I'm assuming that the normal alert comes at the opening of a new bar? You may need to use `BUY[1]` and `SELL[1]` for the delayed alert while keeping the time delay logic.